# Reading file in Cordova Windows 10 app

Tags: cordova, readfile, windows-10-universal

I'm building Cordova app and I'm using cordova-plugin-file to read files. It works fine on Android and iOS, but I can't make it work on Windows 10 Universal app. My code to read the file is:

```
fs.readFromFile = function(base, fileName) {
    pathToFile = base + 'www/' + fileName;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(pathToFile, function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                    resolve(this.result);
                };

                reader.readAsText(file);
            }, reject);
        }, function(er) {
            console.log(er);
            reject();
        });
    });
};
```

And then I call it like:

```
     fs.readFromFile(cordova.file.applicationDirectory, 'lang/' + language + '.json')
        .then(function(content) {
            lang = JSON.parse(content);
            loadFilesCallback().then(resolve);
        });
```

I always get FileError.ENCODING_ERR on Windows 10 only. I tried to change encoding from UTF-8 to Windows-1250, but still the same error.

In plugin documentation I have found that Windos do not support FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer nor FileWriter.write(blob). So am I just doing something wrong or reading and writing is not supported by plugin on Windows 10 Universal App?

Comment: Are you sure that the file is present in the respective folder in windows?

Comment: pretty sure it is. I have tried to renema it and it was throwing NOT_FOUND_ERR.

Comment: Are you using the same app to create file and read file? Because applicationDirectory is private and only the respective app can access the same. DId you tried out cordova.file.externalRootDirectory?

Comment: Its located in www directory with cordova app. So its in application directory. I will try externalRootDirectory, maybe cordova internally transfer files.